# Chrome local storage is not storing dates correctly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

When setting data in Chrome's local storage containing a date, all the data is correctly retrieved except the date that disappears, but I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

```js
await browser.storage.local.remove("ghunt");
var payload = {"ghunt": {
                "cookies": "dummydata",
                "date": new Date(),
                "step": "login"
            }};
console.log("Raw payload => ", payload);
console.log("Putting the payload in local storage...")
await browser.storage.local.set(payload)
console.log("Retrieving data from local storage...")
var storage = await browser.storage.local.get("ghunt");
console.log("Retrieved data => ", storage);
```

The exact same code / commands works perfectly on Firefox.

*PS : I am using WebExtension-Polyfill from Mozilla to provide cross-browser support*

[Firefox output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGs1o.png)
[Chrome output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bggBn.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MDN on [`StorageArea.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/set) (emphasis mine):

> It's generally not possible to store other types, such as `Function`, **`Date`**, `RegExp`, `Set`, `Map`, `ArrayBuffer`, and so on. Some of these unsupported types will restore as an empty object, and some cause set() to throw an error. **The exact behavior here is browser-specific.**

Store `new Date().getTime()`, which is an integer, not `new Date()`.